# Create a text file, read and compare the integer that inside of it

Tags: java, file, integer, text-files, game-physics

I have the following task:

> We would like to keep the highest score of players across previous
>   games. This score will be saved in a file, and will be updated at the
>   end of each game if the current score is higher than the highest score
>   so far.
>
> The highest-score file name should be highscores and should be located
>   in the folder the game was run from. This file will include only one
>   single line with the following content: The highest score so far is:
>   XXX.
>
> If it is the first time we run the game, you need to create the file
>   with the current score. At the end of the next time we run the game,
>   you need to compare the new score with the highest score stored in the
>   file and update the file only if you reach a highest score.

My code is:

```
  public class ScorePersistence {
        private int score;
        private File highscores;
        private int currentHighScore;

        private ScorePersistence(int finalScore) {
            this.score = finalScore;
        }


        public void ShouldUpdate() {
            File highScores = new File("highscores.txt");
            if (highScores.exists()) {
 if (currentHighScore < the score that inside of highscores.txt){
    currentHighScore = the score that inside of highscores.txt
    highscores.write("The highest score so far is: "+ the score that inside of highscores.txt)
}
    else{
    break; //means the currentHighScore is bigger than there is no reason to update the file
}
            }

 else {
//means that there is no file yet, which means this is the first time we run the game on the computer.
    currentHighScore = score;
    highScore.write("The highest score so far is: "+ score).

            }
        }
    }
```

I'm getting the "int finalScore" in the end of the game from the class that in charge of running the levels and the game.

What do you think?
How do you think, should I get the score from that text file and compare it to the "score" that I have received from the current game?

Thanks.
It's a simple offline game. bricks and a ball that hits them.

Answer (score 0):

Is this an online game, or an offline one?

If this is an offline game, I believe reading the text file when loading the game in the beginning and keeping it in a local variable throughout the game would we sufficient. By doing so, you would avoid unnecessary file readings and you could only update the high score when needed.

If this is an online game, I would need more information. How do you handle the server operations? I am asking this because in this case you should also handle file lock requests (multiple users trying to read/write at the same time). I would recommend using a database for this purpose, instead of using a text file.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer. It's an offline game. Can you explain your first answer?

Comment: You don't really need to read the text file every time when the game ends. When you are starting the game you can read the text file once, parse it, convert the score to int or float, and set it to a variable (int highscore).

In order to do that, you can create a method that is called when the game starts and sets the read value from text file. 

By doing so, you can use the highscore variable in the if conditional. Only if the currentscore is greater than highscore, then you call another method to update your variable and update the text in the file.